# How can I to edit or remove the URLs of the authentication by default in Laravel using Inertia JS?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-8, inertiajs

I'm starting a new proyect using Laravel 8 and Inertia JS with VueJS. I'm using the authentication routes and views generated by Inertia, but in my application I don't need the `/register` url, so I need to remove it to avoid other people can enter typing the URL.

How I can to remove it? or where is the place to manage that urls generated by Inertia? or for example, if I don't want to delete the url, but I want to rename it to `/signup` how can I do it?

[image]

I have been looking for information in the inertia documentation but I have not found anything.

This is my web.php routes file and those routes are not here

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\Experimental\RandomController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Inertia\Inertia;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return Inertia::render('Welcome', [
        'canLogin' => Route::has('login'),
        'canRegister' => Route::has('register'),
        'laravelVersion' => Application::VERSION,
        'phpVersion' => PHP_VERSION,
    ]);
});

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
    return Inertia::render('Dashboard');
})->name('dashboard');
```

**UPDATE 1:**
I'm using Laravel Jetstream

Comment: Are you using Laravel Jetstream?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. I forgot put it in the question. Updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't appear that they've documented how you can do this, but it looks possible from the Fortify config file.

Open `config/fortify.php` and comment or remove `Features::registration(),` from the array:

```
use Laravel\Fortify\Features;

'features' => [
    // Features::registration(),
    // ...
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Check auth.php under routes, you should find all the auth routes there. So you can rename the register url to sign up and create a new controller or rename the register user controller.